Activating calligraphic characters in GFS Neohellenic font
Following this "recent" question, I was reminded of the file available at https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb44-2/tb137vieth-otmath.html, where it is observed on page 219

that there is a font called Neohellenic=GFSNeohellenic (avaliable in pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX).
I haven't found anything on how to activate the calligraphic option, as indicated in the guide available at the following link:
https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsneohellenic/doc/GFSNeohellenic-Guide-for-LaTeX.pdf.
I have into MiKTeX these fonts, but I don't see in the guide's PDF how to activate the calligraphic characters shown below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\begin{document}
Short MWE
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}srryh
\end{equation}
GFS Neohellenic Math. 
\end{document}

I not see the exact calligraphic font:


The glyphs are only available in the OpenType math font. Not with pdflatex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{GFS Neohellenic}
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{ABCDEF}$

\end{document}



Thank you very very much.
